# Heroku Java Websocket Endpoint

Tags: java, swing, heroku, websocket

I am trying to build a chat application.

+Server : I use java websocket to create an endpoint. Here is my endpoint:

```
@ServerEndpoint("/server") 
public class ChatServer {
    //My code is ok ! Tested in localhost
}
```

+Client : I use java swing to create GUI. In my localhost, I use this URL :

```
ws://localhost:8080/ChatServer-1.0/server
```

to connect to Server Endpoint and my app run successful.

-> I have deployed my server endpoint to Heroku

[My Heroku Server Endpoint](https://jp-chatting-server.herokuapp.com/)

How can my client to connect to server endpoint ?

I have tried to use:

```
wss://jp-chatting-server.herokuapp.com/server
```

But it gives a 404 code.

Comment: Are you running the app locally with `foreman start`, or are you deploying a war into a servlet container?

Comment: I deploy a war file into a servlet container. (Tomcat server)

Comment: Try getting the app to run with `foreman start`. That's the best way to simulate how Heroku runs the app. And that way you can eliminate other factors (such as Tomcat version).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have used instruction for [webapp-runner](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-webapp-runner). I'm afraid this solution will not work for websockets. It is because support of websocket is not implemented yeat. [Issue with websocket in webapp-runner](https://github.com/jsimone/webapp-runner/issues/38). I see one of the options in using Tomcat 7 and it's custom implementation. Like in [this example](http://privateblog.by/heroku-com-kak-poluchit-realizaciyu-websockets-na-java/).